Mongoose middleware is not being called for findByIdAndDelete
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/relationDatabase');
}

const orderSchema = new Schema({
    item: String,
    price: Number
});

const Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);

const customerSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    orders: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Order"
        }
    ]
});

const Customer = mongoose.model("Customer", customerSchema);

customerSchema.pre('findOneAndDelete',async ()=>{
    console.log("POST MIDDLEWARE");
});

customerSchema.post("findOneAndDelete",  async ()=>{
    console.log("POST MIDDLEWARE");
});

async function deleteCustomer() {
    const deletedCustomer = await Customer.findByIdAndDelete("6644eb4bc7df9bee46d64981");
    console.log(deletedCustomer);
}

let addCustomer=async ()=>{
    let cust1=new Customer({
        name:"john snow",
    })


    let order1=await Order.findOne({item:"burger"});
    let order2=await Order.findOne({item:"pasta"});

    cust1.orders.push(order1);
    cust1.orders.push(order2);

    let res=await cust1.save();

    console.log(res);
} 

deleteCustomer();

tring to call findOneAndDelete MDW but its not able to print anything as it is not called I tried directly using findOneAndDelete but same result not calling MDW findOneAndDelete,i am expecting console.log("POST MIDDLEWARE") to be printed .

You need to Define Middleware Before Compiling Models so just move the pre hook above the mongoose.model call. The findByIdAndDelete() method triggers the findOneAndDelete() middleware as per the docs so your console.log should work just fine if you use findByIdAndDelete(). There is also no need for an async function if you are just logging to console in the hook.

There are 2 issues in this case:
a) Calling pre() or post() after compiling a model does not work in Mongoose in general, refer link 1 below. Therefore please change the order of statements as this:
customerSchema.pre('findOneAndDelete',async ()=>{
    console.log("POST MIDDLEWARE");
});

customerSchema.post("findOneAndDelete",  async ()=>{
    console.log("POST MIDDLEWARE");
});

const Customer = mongoose.model("Customer", customerSchema);

b) findByIdAndDelete does not have an equivalent middleware, write middleware on findOneAndDelete instead, refer link 2 below.
Sample codes enclosed below.
const mongoose = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

run().catch((error) => console.log(error));

async function run() {

  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');

  const someSchema = new Schema({ key1: String });
  someSchema.pre('findOneAndDelete', async function () {
    console.log('findOneAdDelete PRE middleware');
  });
  someSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async function () {
    console.log('findOneAdDelete POST middleware');
  });

  const SomeModel = mongoose.model('SomeModel', someSchema);
  SomeModel.deleteMany();

  await SomeModel.findOneAndDelete({});
  const someId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
  await SomeModel.findByIdAndDelete(someId);
}

Output:
findOneAdDelete PRE middleware
findOneAdDelete POST middleware
findOneAdDelete PRE middleware
findOneAdDelete POST middleware

Links:
1. Define Middleware Before Compiling Models
2. Mongoose pre middleware with findByIdAndDelete
